# AutoScale Implementation in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Auto Scale using Softlayer Java API. 
Is it possible to implement all the scale functions using Java Client?
I found some scale services in API. If you provide me the example code to implement Scale, it will be appreciated.

[image: Scale]

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible here an example to create a scale group:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Location;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Group;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;


public class AutoScale {

    private static String user = "set me";

    private static String apiKey = "set me";

    private static ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Group.Service scaleGroupService = Group.service(client);

        Location location = new Location();
        location.setName("hkg02");

        Guest guest = new Guest();
        guest.setDomain("softlayer.com");
        guest.setHostname("hostnametest");
        guest.setMaxMemory(new Long(1024));
        guest.setPostInstallScriptUri("https://www.softlayer.com/script");
        guest.setStartCpus(new Long (1));
        guest.setDatacenter(location);
        guest.setHourlyBillingFlag(true);
        guest.setLocalDiskFlag(false);
        guest.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode("CENTOS_LATEST");


        Group scaleGroup = new Group();
        scaleGroup.setCooldown(new Long(1800));
        scaleGroup.setMaximumMemberCount(new Long(5));
        scaleGroup.setMinimumMemberCount(new Long(1));
        scaleGroup.setName("testVSI");
        scaleGroup.setRegionalGroupId(new Long(102));
        scaleGroup.setSuspendedFlag(false);
        scaleGroup.setTerminationPolicyId(new Long(2));
        scaleGroup.setVirtualGuestMemberTemplate(guest);
        scaleGroup.setVirtualGuestMemberCount(new Long(0));

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(scaleGroupService.createObject(scaleGroup)));


    }

}
```